# Issues using a Parallax Scrolling Background in Cocos2d?

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, parallax

I am using a Parallax Scrolling Effect in my cocos2d app. I want my Background to continously **scroll**; however, I may be implementing it incorrectly because my background does scroll to the left, but after that, it never comes back again.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) setUpBackground
{

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    // Create the CCParallaxNode
    _backgroundNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
    [self addChild:_backgroundNode z:-2];

    // Create ths prites
    para1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
    para2= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"shipp.png"];

    // Determine relative movement speeds for trees and background
    CGPoint treeSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);
    CGPoint bgSpeed = ccp(0.5, 0.5);

    // Add children to the CCParallexNode
    [_backgroundNode addChild:para1 z:0
                parallaxRatio:treeSpeed
               positionOffset:ccp(160,winSize.height/2)];

    [_backgroundNode addChild:para2 z:1
                parallaxRatio:bgSpeed
               positionOffset:ccp(para1.contentSize.width* para1.scale, winSize.height/2)];

}

- (void)updateBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);
    _backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(_backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));

}
```

Comment: perhaps this helps: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/12/ways-scrolling-cocos2d-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing full codes but I guess you might scheduled `updateBackground()` elsewhere.

In `updateBackground()`, you set background's position, and its positionX is decreasing overtime. That's why it never comes back again.

You have to calculate the width of whole scene, the width of background, and unschedule `updateBackground()` when background reached the edge of scene.